# Modify and manipulate mutiple csv files in directories and subdirectories

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv, os.walk

I have couple of csv files in folders and nested folders that I want to modify.

How can I spot error and any idea to make it work.

I have tried this code. It doesn't work.

```
import csv
import os

for root, subdir, files in os.walk('path'):
    for csvfiles in files:
        if csvfiles.endswith(".csv"):
            paths = os.path.join(root, csvfiles)
            with open(csvfiles, newline='') as input_file:
#read the input csv file
                reader = csv.reader(input_file)
                data = [line for line in reader]
#load the the output file
            with open(csvfiles, 'w', newline='') as output_file:
                writer = csv.writer(output_file)
#add the column name
                writer.writerow(['X', 'Y', 'Width', 'Height', 'Tag'])
                writer.writerows(data)
```

Comment: if you just want to modify the CSV there is no need for separate read  csv.writer is enough just use writer.writerow and remove   writer.writerows(data)

Comment: Actually no.  I am re-writing whole data to csv files. Actually its not the problem here. The problem is I want to manipulate all files in directories. Thanks for the comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change `csvfiles` variable to `paths` while opening the file.

```
import csv
import os

for root, subdir, files in os.walk('path'):
    for csvfiles in files:
        if csvfiles.endswith(".csv"):
            paths = os.path.join(root, csvfiles)
            with open(paths, newline='') as input_file:
#read the input csv file
                reader = csv.reader(input_file)
                data = [line for line in reader]
#load the the output file
            with open(paths, 'w', newline='') as output_file:
                writer = csv.writer(output_file)
#add the column name
                writer.writerow(['X', 'Y', 'Width', 'Height', 'Tag'])
                writer.writerows(data)
```

Comment: It does not work. the csv files over write and only ['X', 'Y', 'Width', 'Height', 'Tag']) left in the file.

Comment: @Wai try now with `a+` mode previously it was `w`.

Comment: It doesn't change anything. :( It doesn't show any error messages.

Comment: @Wai `a+` is to append what you want to achieve. DO you want to update the last row of all the CSV OR just add some row to each CSV?

Comment: I want to add header to my csv files. It worked on individual csv file. But I can't manually add all. :(

Comment: @Wai Ok I think I got the problem When you are reading the csv you are using `csvfiles` instead of `paths`. I have updated my code try it now.